# Disable automatic subticks on semilogyaxis plot with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I found many questions regarding why subtics do not appear on a semilogyaxis plot. But I actually would like to *not* have those subticks as this adds *too many* ticks so that my plot looks pretty full. And I did not find this.

It would be great if one could do this without manual fiddling like e.g. setting the y-ticks manually.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable the minor ticks on the y axis, set `yminorticks=false`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    yminorticks=false
]
\addplot  [thick, black] {exp(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```